# didFinishLaunchingWithOptions doesn't find any rootcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I need to parse some XML that triggers an NSURLConnection. After the parsing finished, I receive some data and then I set the root view controller. My problem is that application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: returns before the composeRootController method and an error occurs because the application cannot find any root view controller. How can I wait until composeRootController returns?

My code is the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self xmlConnect];
    return YES;
}
```

here xmlConnect function is implemented for parsing

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //convertim la data a string
    NSString *receivedDataAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading %@", receivedDataAsString);

    //xml parsing
    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:receivedData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];

    self.receivedData = nil;

    BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

    if(success)
        NSLog(@"No Errors");
    else
        NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");

    [self composeRootController];
}
```

here composeRootController sets rootcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your

```
 [self composeRootController];
```

inside 
     didFinishLaunching...

And have composeRootController call xmlConnect.

You might have to move the xmlConnect method out of your app delegate.